# GPU glitches? Crashing both Linux Mint & Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, nvidia-graphics-card

My GPU is apparently dying on me. Yesterday it caused a BSOD on Windows and crashed MDM on Linux Mint. It caused a few strange graphical glitches before crashing on both operating systems. Today, i cleaned the card and it's happening on the BIOS, GRUB, and during the OS start as well. When the OS boots, it crashes after a few seconds. Windows BSOD's and Linux keeps restarting MDM and crashing.

Here are some screens:

[image: linux]
[image: windows]

Has anyone experienced this? Or should i just buy a new card because this one is gone? It's an NVIDIA GTX 560.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced similar issues on a number of graphics cards, and in fact, with that exact model of GPU, [I was able to fix the issue by baking it](http://forums.evga.com/tm.aspx?m=696061).

Essentially:

1. Strip the card down by removing fans, shrouds, cables and fans and cleaning thermal coumpound off.
2. Rest the card on foil balls supporting things like the fan headers
3. Bake the card in 385 degree preheated oven for 9 minutes

Once the cards are cool, reapply thermal paste.

It may not help, and your video card may be beyond saving, but if the issue is being caused by micro-fractures in the soldering, properly baking should be enough to fix it and get it running good-as-new again.  And if it doesn't work, the worst you've done is wasted a few cents worth of foil and an hour or so of your time, so... no reason not to try.